# Past perfect tense usage

Tags: grammar

Yesterday I was waiting for my friend at bus stop to go somewhere.I was there 2pm.I did not see my fried till 5pm.It was about for 3 hours that I waited for him and I came back home.Then I called him up and asked why he did not come.He answered he was busy and in somewhere thats why he had not come there.

Here is it correct past perfect had not come.

Comment: Yes, _had not come_ is fine in this context, but there are other problems with the passage. Proofreading is off-topic, but, for one thing, you **must** leave a space after a full stop (period) or a comma.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Either "did not come" or "had not come" would work, but using "did not come" and "had not come" in successive sentences is a bit odd. Even if either tense would be valid on its own, you're probably better using the same tense for both.